# How to use apply/custom function to two linked dataframes with conditions imposed on columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which are as follows:

```py
df1

    A   B   C
0   Y1  X1  1000
1   Y2  X2  3000
2   Y3  X1  2000
3   Y4  X1  5000
4   Y5  X3  7000
5   Y6  X4  1500
6   Y7  X2  1200
7   Y8  X4  1100
df2

      K    L   M   N
0   Y1  X1  40  2020-06
1   Y1  X1  30  2020-05
2   Y2  X2  50  2020-01
3   Y1  X1  90  2020-04
4   Y3  X1  10  2020-06
5   Y2  X2  40  2020-04
6   Y3  X1  55  2020-03
7   Y4  X1  12  2019
8   Y5  X3  80  2020-04
9   Y5  X3  60  2020-05
10  Y6  X4  90  2020-06
11  Y7  X2  30  2020-03
12  Y8  X4  50  2020-02
13  Y7  X2  60  2020-01
```

What I want from two above data frame is that I want to add a new column to the df1 by imposing condition to the column **N** of second dataframe i.e add rows of same type of whose value is <= 2020-05(year-week string format). The desired output I want is :

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4","Y5","Y7","Y8"],
                    "B":["X1","X2","X1","X1","X3","X2","X4"],
                    "C":[1000,3000,2000,5000,7000,1200,1100],
                    "P":[30+90,50+40,55,12,80+60,30+60,50]})

df3

     A  B     C     P
0   Y1  X1  1000    120
1   Y2  X2  3000    90
2   Y3  X1  2000    55
3   Y4  X1  5000    12
4   Y5  X3  7000    140
5   Y7  X2  1200    90
6   Y8  X4  1100    50
```

That is by imposed condition,I add rows which satisfy the conditions of df2 (except column N) and then finally add a column P to the df1.

For simplicity I took an example, actual data set is big.
Can anyone help me to write a function to obtain my desired output, or how can I use an apply function or iterrows etc. I am new to programming and I got stuck.
Help appreciated.

Comment: are columns A and B from first df related to K and L of df2? also can you explain more about your logic, how is less than 13 used?

Comment: I don't see how your condition on column `N` *(add rows of same type of whose value is less than 13)* is used. It looks like column `P` is the result of grouping by `(K, L)` and then summing on `M`. And that's regardless of `N`'s value.

Comment: @anky_91 yes they are realted , column A of first contain distinct entries where Column B entries are not unique, But column K and L entries are not distinct in df 2 .

Comment: @Arnaud I just took an example, actually the data set is big, At first i also thought by grouping idea, but it didnt work so I have to imposed the condition on column N

Comment: Where does `7` come from at the first row of `df3['P']`? Also why row `4` of `df3` has `P` value when `df2` has `N` value of 40 for`Y5, X3`?

Comment: Please show a sufficient and necessary example where your stated condition on N is trackable.

Comment: @QuangHoang same question here: the condition on N is unclear. 7 comes from 4+3 in column M probably.

Comment: On another note, you can just filter `df2` with `df2_filtered = df2[df2['N']<13].copy()`.

Comment: @Arnaud yes 7 came from addition of 4 and 3

Comment: @QuangHoang I only did operation on column M , column N is only for imposing conditon to add a new column to df1 with operations df2

Comment: @anky_91 there is no logic to use 13 i used it as an example, actually column N is date and I want to apply condtion on date by year week number. Due to data policy I cant share the actual data so I wrote my requirements by taking an example

Comment: @anky_91 I updated the OP. Please look into it

Answer (score 0):

You could first filter out rows that do not follow your conditions on column N, and then groupby & sum on column M to obtain your values for column P:

```
df_tmp = df2.query("N < 13").groupby([K, L])["M"].sum()
df3 = df1.join(df_tmp, how="left").fillna(0)
```

Comment: throws an error if I pass date in query example df2.query("year == 2020-06"), i.e creating problem for string data type elements in column N

Comment: That is because you gave an example where N represented integers. So we can only answer for that very precise case. If your input is with datetime, then adapt your question accordingly...

Comment: is there any way to filter df2 , and add the obtained sum entries to the df 1 to corresponding (Xi,Yi)? Is there any way to create our own function and then apply to dataframe?

Comment: Yes, using a left join followed with `fillna(0)` to replace missing values with zeros. Edited my answer.